# Browser(s) randomly closes

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I have an issue here in my Company where the browsers (FF, IE, Chrome) randomly closes on a few computers.

I've used Process monitor to try and trace down the issue, but I'm kinda lost.

All it actually says is:

```
Exit Status:    1
User Time:  0.7020045 seconds
Kernel Time:    3.6348233 seconds
Private Bytes:  12.865.536
Peak Private Bytes: 16.277.504
Working Set:    33.517.568
Peak Working Set:   38.117.376
```

Things I've already done to troubleshoot:

- Updated drivers
- Scanned for spyware
- Scanned for Virusses
- Increased memory
- Performed memory check
- Uninstalled Anti Virus
- Updated browsers

We use the HP 840 G2 laptops.

Answer (score 1):

Use process explorer and do not try to look at the closing browser processes. Instead use the menu and increase the delay option that highlights newly spawned processes. This process (apparently a malware) is quick enough to run so with the delay you introduce in Procexp you can actually see what new process started and ended. It will be there even if the process executed and ended within a second. This way you can find what process is being spawned. Two menu options below will help
View->Scroll to new processes
Edit->Difference highlight duration
Beyond this there are other ways. You can use WMI to trace. You an use security auditing (gpedit) to trace process spawned etc.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I found some more info with Process Explorer, but i still need some help.

At the moment of the browser crashes, what i see happening is the following:

winnit.exe > Services.exe > WmiPrvSE.exe

(Under WmiPrvSE.exe i see some more processes getting launched)

wscript.exe > cmd.exe > taskkill.exe (this repeats 4 times)

Any idea's on where to go from here?

Comment: That't it! :) I wanted to tell you earlier.. "look out for wscript or cscript".. anyway.. Not an elegant fix but based on how much urgent the situation is to fix this, just disable taskkill via registry. Search for .vbs scripts in they system. You can grep directories when you find 1 or a few in any.. and search for browser exe name like "iexplore.exe" or "chrome.exe" .. Mostly you will find vbs files.. if not this may be dynamic.. in which case

Comment: we have to go back , enable taskkill and do "auditing" with local group policy (recommended as there are other ways) and ensure you trace and analyze everything - which process, where it loads from etc. Seems like an insider job...

Comment: I tracked down the issue and think it's connected to SCCM. After uninstalling SCCM the browser didn't crash the whole weekend.
We are still figuring out what is causing this exactly, but I just wanted to thank you for your time and effort. Couldn've have done this without you.